# Grails version upgrade from 2.4.4 to 2.5.3

Tags: grails

I created a simple project in grails 1.3.7..Now I am doing the task of version change.At first I took my 1.3.7 project to 2.4.4.It ran perfectly.
The changes I have made in my files  BuildConfig.groovy file ,urlmapping,index.gsp,applicationcontext.xml,application.pro‌​perties

```
       applicationContext.xml

             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
    <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml"/>
    <!--<property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />-->
</bean>

<bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
    <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml"/>
    <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication"/>
</bean>

<bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="grailsApplication"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager"/>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="grailsResourceLoader" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean">-->
<!--<property name="grailsResourceHolder" ref="grailsResourceHolder" />-->
<!--</bean>-->

<!--<bean id="grailsResourceHolder" scope="prototype" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsResourceHolder">-->
<!--<property name="resources">-->
<!--<value>classpath*:**/grails-app/**/*.groovy</value>-->
<!--</property>-->
<!--</bean>    -->

<bean id="characterEncodingFilter"
      class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
    <property name="encoding">
        <value>utf-8</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="conversionService"            
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

urlMappings

```
   class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
       }
     }
```

in index.gsp file

```
       %{--<li>Groovy version:    

            ${org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()}  </li>--}% to


      <li>Groovy version: ${GroovySystem.getVersion()}</li>
```

Now I'm trying to convert it from 2.4.4 to 2.5.3.But an error is showing up.

the error is

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error 

 initializing the application:Error creating bean with name   

 'defaultGrailsintConverter':

  Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is  

         org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

 Could not autowire field: private   

            org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver   

       org.grails.databinding.converters.web.LocaleAwareNumberConverter.

localeResolver;
```

Please help me with this.Should I compile spring security plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to list the steps you performed in the upgrade.  What files did you change, what dependencies did you change, etc.

Furthermore, there are some blogs out there about upgrading.  Not all apps use the same pieces of Grails, so not all upgrades are the same.  Here are a couple:
http://totalprogus.blogspot.com/2015/03/upgrade-grails-244-to-250.html
http://peedeebeesblog.blogspot.com/2015/06/moving-up-grails-243-to-250.html

Finally, each rev of Grails has a release notes that offers instruction on what might need doing during an upgrade.  Here are the notes for 2.5.0:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v2.5.0

Your error doesn't look like it involves the Spring Security Plugin, just Spring injection, though it's a little hard to tell with the formatting.

Comment: Don't put it in the comments.. Add it to your question.

Comment: As you mentioned your initial project, the 1.3.7 version was a 'simple' project you might find it's a less troublesome process creating a completely new Grails 2.5 project, and bringing the domains/controllers/views and any src over after the project is setup and plugins/dependencies specified.   This approach offered a smoother upgrade path for me.